# recursive diff to create a patch and apply patch recursively

Tags: diff, patch

I'm running into trouble using patch.  I have 2 folders with many subfolders and files.

`diff -ur backup/www/  www/ > sync.patch`

Next, I'm trying to apply the patch.

`patch < sync.patch`

It asks me `File to patch:` as you can see.

```
|diff -ur ./backup/www/members/categorize.php ./www/members/categorize.php
|--- ./backup/www/members/categorize.php   2012-12-13 15:19:41.000000000 -0500
|+++ ./www/members/categorize.php   2012-10-15 23:32:12.000000000 -0400
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

The file ./www/members/categorize.php exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to investigate the `-p` flag for `patch`, which controls the way that directory prefixes are treated.  See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch).

Comment: thanks, I used `patch -t -p0 < sync.patch` to apply the patches